# Trying to close Excel through an Excel macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I made a button (not an activeX button) and assigned a macro that is coded to kill the EXCEL.EXE task. When activated it gives me an error message saying it cannot close. Is it even possible to kill the excel task through excel?

Here's my code. I'm positive it works.

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
intAnswer = _
MsgBox("Do you want to close Excel?", _
    vbYesNo, "Prompt")

If intAnswer = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "Excel will close."

Else
    MsgBox "Excel will remain open."
End If

oShell.Run "taskkill /im EXCEL.EXE", , True
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Application.Quit`?

Comment: @SO how do i use that then?

Comment: @Rocketboy721 use taskkill from outside excel, while inside excel use `Application.Quit` as S O suggested). Anyway, ActiveX button is not that bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Application.Quit` method :

```
intAnswer = _
MsgBox("Do you want to close Excel?", _
    vbYesNo, "Prompt")

If intAnswer = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "Excel will close."
    Application.Quit

Else
    MsgBox "Excel will remain open."
End If
```

Consider to use as well

```
ThisWorkbook.Save
```

if you want to save the work before closing the application. You can find out more about the Application object [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198091(v=office.15).aspx).

Comment: @Rocketboy721 if it works, don't forget to accept the answer so that other users with your same problem will know where to look at ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adding this up front:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts=False
ThisWorkbook.Save
```